# How to retrieve the current BrowserWindow in the render process of electron

Tags: electron

How can I retrieve the current BrowserWindow from within the JavaScript file in the render process of an electron v12 application.

Comment: The `BrowserWindow` is a main-process API only. However if you share *why* you need the `BrowserWindow` in the renderer process I may be able to help.

Comment: I would like to create a new modal dialog from the render process of an existing window and would need the parent BrowserWindow.

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66700056/6577664 if that's the case then you'll have the `BrowserWindow` in the `mainWindow` variable on the main-process once the main-process receives the message to create the modal.