# How can I open a new modal browser windows from a render process in electron

Tags: electron

When using the `new BrowserWindow` statement in the render process the following exception is thrown: `TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor`.

How can I create a new modal BrowserWindow from a render process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `BrowserWindow` in the renderer process. Only in the main process:

[image]

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindow

The two processes must communicate via a channel:

```js
// main process
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(function () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } });
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
});

ipcMain.on('go!', (ev, url) => {
//         ^^^^^
//         A channel called "go!"
  new BrowserWindow().loadURL(url);
});
```

```js
// renderer process
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  ipcRenderer.send('go!', 'https://www.discogs.com/artist/7760-Japanese-Telecom');
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button>detroit techno</button>
    <script>require('./renderer.js')</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you click on the button "detroit techno" (as you should!):

1. The renderer process sends a message with a url
2. The main process picks up the message and open the url in a new window

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great feedback. Just to make sure I understand: if a render process needs to open a simple dialog (for example to enter some text) this must be performed via the main process?

Comment: @doberkofler If you want to use the `BrowserWindow` API then yes.

Comment: Please note that you do not need to set `nodeIntegration=true` to enable IPC communication between processes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69605882/1244884