# How to make electron preload file use the same class instance

Tags: electron, signalr, svelte, signalr-hub

I am developing an Electron (v15.2) app which has to be able to open multiple windows displaying data from **shared data sources**.

Since I am not an experienced electron developer, I naively thought that the dependencies I create in the main window will be accessible to the child windows when I inject them (I created a pseudo dependency injection solution using svelte store) but to my surprise the class instances in child windows are actually brand new.

So digging more into that I realized that the problem lies within the context isolation, which actually makes sense, so I decided to create the required central part of the data sources - which is a **SignalR websocket hub connection** instance, in the preload script
and then expose that connection instance to all the windows to use.

The thing is that for each window a new preload.js is called, which will create new connection instance each time I open a new window. (I tested it by creating a random value and comparing it between windows)

That is not what I need, so is there any solution I could try to make this work? Maybe completely different approach exists of which I'm not aware of. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: If your main process can also be the one responsible for setting up and dispatching data then you can perhaps look into setting up IPC channels between your main process and your renderer processes via the ContextBridge API and your preload scripts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69607820/1244884

Comment: Yes, things in `preload` already in the browser scope, since `window` is available there. If your initial data is same, then you can create a folder called `shared` and then load this file from both `main` and `renderer`.

Comment: @customcommander Yes I did take that into consideration, but I would have to pass all the data flow through to the main process and back, which I thought could be slowing down the application (the data flow can be very high speed). Other solution I thought of would be to pass that reference from the main process, but I read that all the instances passed from there are serialized and proxied and whatnot, so I figured that probably wouldn't work too

Comment: @windmaomao thank you for answer. Do I understand correctly that I should make a separate file, instantiate the connection there, and then import it in main process? Could you perhaps write down a little example of that? The actual implementation is what I'm not sure about.

Comment: I don't know much about your exact use case but if I had multiple renderer processes needing to display shared data I would definitely want to get that data from a single controller (i.e. the main process) and let it manage the burden of getting the data up to date and communicated evenly. I don't know how much data you need to process but I would still use IPC unless it is proven inefficient. You _could_ use the remote API but Electron has dropped support for it. If you want it you need to use a community-supported package.