# Sending commands to the web app in electron renderer process since contextIsolation changes

Tags: electron

I understand that contextIsolation changes are introduced for security purposes, and i read about contextBridge which exposes custom API to the webapp running in the renderer process so web app can control electron app in which is runing.

**electron preload script**

```
const contextBridge = require("electron").contextBridge;
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronApi", {
  'doSomething' : function () {
     // some code to execute
  }
});
```

**web app**

```
window.electronApi.doSomething();
```

This is perfectly clear and i understand why is this done this way.

However, i do not understand how can communication work the other way, so how can electron execute web app commands? Let's take following example, web app has window.someWebAppMethod defined and electron should execute it

**web app**

```
window.someWebAppMethod = function () {
  // do somehing web app related
}
```

**electron preload script**

```
window.someWebAppMethod()
```

^^ this does not work because of contextIsolation which was whole point of contextIsolation, but i still need to have a certain way of triggering web app commands from electron. Most obvious reason is let's say i have electron main menu with command labeled "Open Quick Jump" which should tell the web app loaded in rendered process to execute method which will show the "Quick Jump" function of the web app.

Maybe i'm missing something painfully obvious, but i'd still appreciate any help i can get.

Thanks

Comment: In this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69605882/1244884) I showed an example IPC communication between the main and renderer processes including the main process talking directly to the renderer process. Since the main process own the renderer BrowserWindow instance it can use it to access its WebContents and send messages to the renderer that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way of doing this. Not sure it's obvious or if it is secure enough, but here it is:

**electron preload script**

```
const contextBridge = require("electron").contextBridge;

let doSomethingInWebApp = null;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronApi", {
  'exposeDoSomethingInWebApp' : function (callback) {
     doSomethingInWebApp = callback;
  }
});
```

**web app**

```
if (window.electronApi && window.electronApi.exposeDoSomethingInWebApp) {
  window.electronApi.exposeDoSomethingInWebApp(function () {
    // execute whatever you need to execute in webapp
  });
}
```

**electron preload script**

```
if (doSomethingInWebApp) {
  // execute previously defined custom behavior in web app
  doSomethingInWebApp();
}
```

So it's quite simple and it works.