# Electron IPC communication throwing error?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I worked the problem for several hours now and I still can't figure it out...

Here are some parts of my code:

**main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;

// ...

const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
    });
    
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    
    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// ...

ipcMain.on("exit", (evt, arg) => {
    app.quit();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="exit">Exit</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

document.getElementById("exit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    ipcRenderer.send("exit");
});
```

The app should close by pressing the 'exit' button.

The error I get is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Please help me to get the basic communication correct.

I tried using the preload.js, but that made it even more complicated.

Comment: Have a read on [context isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation). Can also add `contextIsolation: false` under nodeIntegration but it is not recommended

Comment: yea, that works. But its more of a workaround than a clean and valid solution

Comment: A clean solution would involve keeping the default security settings (nodeIntegration false, contextIsolation true) and using the Context Bridge API — See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605882/electron-setting-up-ipc-communication-between-main-and-renderer-processes/69607820#69607820

Answer (score 0):

Your index.js code would be better run as a preload.js script (see below), which has access to Node API, then you would not need node integration (which may be a security issue)...

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
// ...

const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        },
    });
    
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
    
    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// ...

ipcMain.on("exit", (evt, arg) => {
    app.quit();
});
```

preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

// When document has loaded, initialize
document.onreadystatechange = (event) => {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        document.getElementById('exit').addEventListener("click", event => {
            ipcRenderer.send('exit');
        });
    }
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="exit">Exit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better to use `contextBridge` in preload to expose the api in renderer. Which makes those functions bind to window and be used in other renderer js files.

Comment: The whole reason for using IPC is to avoid granting Node API access to the renderer process.

Comment: IPC & Context Bridge aren't mutually exclusive. Preload script is a step in the right direction but it could use the Context Bridge API to provide an API to your renderer; the API using IPC behind the scene.